# Mifare Classic 1k APDU command for retrieving tag UID

Tags: java, nfc, mifare, apdu

As the title says; is there a APDU command for retrieving the UID of a tag? I am using Java, with an ACR122-u cardreader and the `javax.smartcardio.*` package and I want to get the UID from a tag on the scanner. The smartcardio library can send CommandAPDU's but I need to figure out what APDU to send. Google has not been very friendly to me on this one, providing me with thousands of unhelpful datasheets of some sort...

Any help would be great :)

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011726/reading-block-from-mifare-classic-using-javax-smartcardio) can help you! [rado](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1607656/rado) already asked something like this and had the answer to this question in his question. I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 10):

Better late than never but there is actually an APDU to JUST retrieve the UID: (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00

FF CA 00 00 00

In Java: `byte[] getuid = new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };`

If you send this APDU, the response data will be just the UID of the card :) (Much easier than having more info and having to set an offset to get just the info you need...)

Comment: I believe that you need to improve you question, adding the entire structure that's make possible to send this command, because is more easy to see here than click in a link.

Comment: He has plenty of other posts explaining how to send and recieve APDUs to cards, with its source codes. I'm just telling him the APDU that he has to send to retrieve specifically the UID.

Answer (score 0):

The APDU Command for Read UID is

```
byte[] baReadUID = new byte[5];

    baReadUID = new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xCA, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00 };
```

[All Complete code is here....](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052363/3073945)