# Locking mechanism of Mifare Classic 1K

Tags: java, nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

The procedure of Mifare Classic 1K is

1. Polling for tags
2. Authenticate those tags
3. If authentication succeded then read/write.

I already completed those procedures and also read and write data from specific sectors.

Command for **Polling for tags** is

```
new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0xD4, (byte) 0x4A,
                (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00 }
```

**Authentication command** is

```
new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x04, 
                                    (byte) 0x60,(byte) 0x00 };
```

Here "(byte) 0x01" is the Sector 1

And **Write on Sector 1, block 5 is**

```
new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xD4,
             (byte)    0x40,(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0x05,(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, 
             (byte) 0x03,(byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07,(byte) 0x08, 
             (byte) 0x09,(byte) 0x0A,(byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D,(byte) 0x0E, 
             (byte) 0x0F, (byte) 0x10};
```

Here

```
(byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x03,(byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0x06, (byte) 0x07,(byte) 0x08,(byte) 0x09,(byte) 0x0A,(byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0x0D,(byte) 0x0E,(byte) 0x0F,(byte) 0x10
```

is data those are writing on block 5 on Sector 1.

**Read From Sector 1 and Block 5** Command is

```
new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x05, (byte) 0xD4, (byte) 0x40,
                (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x05 };
```

[My Related Complete Code is here...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26052363/3073945)

My Problem is how can I "Lock/make read only" a block from a specific sector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The authentication keys and the access conditions for each sector of a MIFARE card are located in the last block of that sector (the *sector trailer*). You can update this block with new access conditions and authentication keys using a regular write command.

The sector trailer looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------+--------------+----+-----------------------------+
|  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |  8 |  9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
+-----------------------------+--------------+----+-----------------------------+
|            Key A            | Access Bits  | GP |            Key B            |
|          (6 bytes)          |  (3 bytes)   | B  |          (6 bytes)          |
+-----------------------------+--------------+----+-----------------------------+
```

So the access bits are located in byte 6-8 and look like this:

```
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
        | Bit 0 | Bit 1 | Bit 2 | Bit 3 | Bit 4 | Bit 5 | Bit 6 | Bit 7 |
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
Byte 6: | nC2_3 | nC2_2 | nC2_1 | nC2_0 | nC1_3 | nC1_2 | nC1_1 | nC1_0 |
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
Byte 7: |  C1_3 |  C1_2 |  C1_1 |  C1_0 | nC3_3 | nC3_2 | nC3_1 | nC3_0 |
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
Byte 8: |  C3_3 |  C3_2 |  C3_1 |  C3_0 |  C2_3 |  C2_2 |  C2_1 |  C2_0 |
        +-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Where nCx_y = not Cx_y and "C1_x, C2_x, C3_x" is the access condition for block x:

- C1_3, C2_3, C3_3: sector trailer (block 3 in this sector)
- C1_2, C2_2, C3_2: block 2 in this sector
- C1_1, C2_1, C3_1: block 1 in this sector
- C1_0, C2_0, C3_0: block 0 in this sector

You can find a detailed list of possible access conditions in the MIFARE 1K datasheet: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf

Comment: It seems that the link to the datasheet is broken, but I found the file [here](http://datasheet.elcodis.com/pdf2/106/20/1062046/mf1s503x.pdf).