# Mifare Access condition calculation

Tags: permissions, nfc, rfid, mifare, contactless-smartcard

I am aware of this post :- [Locking mechanism of Mifare Classic 1K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885861/locking-mechanism-of-mifare-classic-1k/27907089#27907089)

However, it is really not clear - how a value like `FF 07 80 FF` is calculated in this string:

```
D3 F7 D3 F7 D3 F7 FF 07 80 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

This means that the blocks can be read with key A and written with Key B but does not allow inc/dec.

How should the access bits look like if I have to support increment and decrement operations. I understand that  C1, C2 and C3 must be 1,1,0 how does this reflect to the byte 6, 7 and 8.

Any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

The access bits `FF 07 80` translate to

```
C1 = 0x0 => C1_3 = 0, C1_2 = 0, C1_1 = 0, C1_0 = 0
C2 = 0x0 => C2_3 = 0, C2_2 = 0, C2_1 = 0, C2_0 = 0
C3 = 0x8 => C3_3 = 1, C3_2 = 0, C3_1 = 0, C3_0 = 0
```

So the sector trailer can be read and written using **key A only** (`Cx_3 = 0 0 1`). All operations (read, write, increment, decrement, etc) can be performed on the data blocks using **key A only** (`Cx_{0,1,2} = 0 0 0`, key B is disabled due to the access conditions of the trailer block).

If you want be able to read all blocks with key A, write with key B, perform value block increments with key B and perform value block decrement, etc. with keys A and B, you could use access conditions like this:

- sector trailer write with key B only: `Cx_3 = 0 1 1`
- data/value blocks: read/decrement with key A, write/increment with key B: `Cx_{0,1,2} = 1 1 0`

  ```
  C1_3 = 0, C1_2 = 1, C1_1 = 1, C1_0 = 1 => C1 = 0x7
  C2_3 = 1, C2_2 = 1, C2_1 = 1, C2_0 = 1 => C2 = 0xF
  C3_3 = 1, C3_2 = 0, C3_1 = 0, C3_0 = 0 => C3 = 0x8
  ```

This leads to the access bits `08 77 8F`. Hence, you sector trailer could look like this (with key A = `D3F7D3F7D3F7` and key B = `000000000000`):

```
D3F7D3F7D3F7 08778F FF 000000000000
```

Comment: Every answer so far, assumes sectors with 4 blocks. What about for Mifare 4k whose higher sectors have 16 blocks????