# RFID MIFARE 1K memory contents

Tags: format, access-control, rfid, mifare

Below is a dump from the sample card that came with the RC522, I have omitted the repeating parts.

What exactly is the data stored at the first block of every sector? In this case *FF 07 80 69 FF FF FF FF FF FF*.

Also what are those bytes after the ATQA bytes, that simply count from 62 to 69?

(fyi this card is in its factory state; it has not been written to by any system- however other new cards from other sources have the same bytes written)

And what exactly is the memory of a Mifare card used for in the usual application? (I have read that most access control systems only read the UID.)

```
mfrc522.PICC_DumpToSerial
Card UID: C1 44 53 63
Card SAK: 08
PICC type: MIFARE 1KB
Sector Block   0  1  2  3   4  5  6  7   8  9 10 11  12 13 14 15  AccessBits
  15     63   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
         62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         61   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
         60   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
...
   0      3   00 00 00 00  00 00 FF 07  80 69 FF FF  FF FF FF FF  [ 0 0 1 ] 
          2   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          1   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00  [ 0 0 0 ] 
          0   C1 44 53 63  B5 08 04 00  62 63 64 65  66 67 68 69  [ 0 0 0 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The last block of each sector (i.e. block 3, block 7, ... block 63) is the sector trailer. It contains the access keys and the access conditions for the sector. See [Mifare 1K authentication keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28051227/2425802) for the exact format and [Locking mechanism of Mifare Classic 1K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27907089/2425802) / [Mifare Access condition calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275712/2425802) on how the access bits are calculated.

The first block of the first sector (block 0) is the manufacturer block. It usually contains anti-collision parameters and some manufacturer specific data. I don't think that NXP ever published any information about the exact format of that data. I'm a bit surprised that your card contains the sequence `62 63 64 65  66 67 68 69` there, since usually there was some information about IC production there (batch number, production data, etc.)

Comment: Actually I can tell the first sector contains the UID, ATQA and SAK, followed by incremental ++1 counting to fill the rest of the block.

Comment: But what is the point of having keys that control access to the block that are visible to anyone that dumps the memory? Doesn't that defeat any security that having a key would provide in the first place if it is visible to everyone?

Comment: @cds333 I'm not sure where you got that card from and if it's a genuine MIFARE 1K, but at least in the past, MIFARE cards had more sophisticated information (about production) in the manufacturer block.

Comment: @cds333 Key access control works perfectly fine. Obviously, you can only dump the memory if you have the necessary access keys for reading the data. Since the card arrived in transport configuration (read/write access with key A, key A set to (probably) FFFFFFFFFFFF, your application could successfully read the data. Note that it was not able to read key A through (and displays that area as 000000000000).

Comment: 00 00 00 00 00 00 is actually one of the default keys listed in the "known keys" array. I didn't notice that until you pointed that out just now. The card is likely not genuine Mifare, it came with the MFRC522 arduino kit which is like $6. Thanks for the clarification!